# ui-grid is not shown

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

We were using ng-grid but after we upgraded to latest angularjs we were getting an error about n.swap is not a function and nothing was rendered. I decided to upgrade to ui-grid, I followed the tutorial for the Upgrading. I see no more errors in the Development Tools Console, but the grid is not visible when I activate the tab. Our tabs are defined as

```html
<div class="widget-content">
                <div class="scrollable widget-resize">
                    <div class="padd">
                        @Html.Partial("_EditFormAlerts")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 panel-container">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#general" ng-class="{true: 'invalid-tab', false: ''}[form.editItemGeneralForm.$invalid]">@Labels.general</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#history" ng-class="{true: 'invalid-tab', false: ''}[form.editItemHistoryForm.$invalid]">@Labels.priceHistory</a></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 panel-container">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="general">
                                @Html.Partial("EditItem")
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="history">
                                @Html.Partial("EditItemHistory")
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

There are more tabs, but I am only showing 2 relevant tabs. The FAQ suggests to use ng-if to properly show the grid and refers to this http://plnkr.co/edit/LtpFnDUTofuxitb4Vh9x?p=preview but I can not figure out how to apply this solution to our tabs.

Comment: Using explicit height and width in px for the gridStyle class allows grid to be visible, but this is not a bullet-proof solution. I'd rather use ng-if instead

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a height style to your grid div:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ng-if="tabShown" style="height:200px;"></div>
```

After adding that in your plnkr I see your data :) I'm also only seeing 2 tabs declared in your plnkr.

Comment: I added explicit width (in px) and height (in px) to my gridStyle class in css and it resolved the problem but my question was about figuring out ng-if for my case (pills defined as I showed in the code). In any case, right now there are only 2 places where we're using ui-grid, so this is not a high priority problem.

Comment: The post is a little ambiguous as to what is being asked. You certainly can use ng-if to show your grid based on some model value of your choice. I'd assume your checking for some sort of value and if it's there then show the grid?

Comment: No, the problem is that when I activate the tab, the grid is not shown. There is a talk about it in the FAQ and the recommended solution is to use ng-if. My problem is that I don't know what should the condition be for my tabs. There is no specific model value. In any case, using fixed width and height fixed the problem